# set row destination when conditionally copying (google sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

All.

I'm a complete novice at scripting but through trial and error have managed to adapt a script I found for splitting a document into separate sheets based on a condition of `column D`.

The sheet to be split is called `MASTER`, and I've already adapted a script to create the relevant tabs for each condition of `column D` (they are just numbers).

What I'm not able to do is to set the data to be pasted in to the new sheets from `row 8` down (rather than `row 1`) - this is because I want each of the new sheets to have a static header occupying the first 7 rows. Probably a stupid question, but I can't figure it out and it would be great if I could.

the existing code is:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var master = ss.getSheetByName('MASTER');
var colWidth = master.getMaxColumns();


function copyRowsOnCondition() {
  var data = master.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=7;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][3].length<16){ 
    Logger.log(data[n][3])
     var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][3].toString().replace(/ /g,''));
     var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);
     master.getRange(n+1,1,1,colWidth).copyTo(destRange); 
     }
  }// loop
}
```

Any help massively appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DestRange` will always be the last row with no data. So if your sheet has data in `B2` for example, the function will copy into row 3. There are multiple ways around that, for example get the last row into a variable first and if it is less than 7 make it equal 7

Comment: I can't believe I didn't just try that to start with. I've populated the headers first (dead easy) and now it works perfectly. Thanks for answering. You are a gent.